# Open any Solidworks 2015 3d model format in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, 3d, solidworks

We have models of our products designed in SolidWorks 2015. In a .NET (C#) desktop application I need to *load that model* (3d display already implemented using OpenGL) and *be able to understand its parts* (their dimensions and relative locations).
Are there any means to do so using *any of* [Solidworks 2015 export formats](http://help.solidworks.com/2015/English/SolidWorks/sldworks/c_Importing-Exporting_SOLIDWORKS_Documents.htm)?

There are two related SO questions
".NET library to open cad models/drawings" (2012)
"Importing AutoCAD/Solidworks drawings/objects into winforms?" (2010)

My Google search:
"X3D.NET" (X3D library for .NET) - looks dead
"Sharky" - dead (no download available)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found a way through their native [3DXML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3DXML) format. You need to [register at Dassault Systemes](https://iam.3ds.com/self_service/login/service/3dxmldoc/?redirect=http%3a%2f%2fmedia%2e3ds%2ecom%2f3dxml%2f3dxmldoc%2f3DXML_Specification_4%2e3%2ezip) to get their "DS Passport". It's for free - you don't even need a Solid Works licence but the registration process (receiving final confirmation) may take a few hours.

When successfully registered, download set of XSD files (its download link at the moment is [this](http://www.3ds.com/3ds-passport/downloads/?xtmc=3dxml_xsd&xtcr=1)).

Use Visual Studio tool `xsd.exe /c 3DXML.xsd` to generate C# (de)serialization class for loading 3DXML structure file `NameSetTree.3dxml` (part names bound to physical files within 3DXML file /i.e. zip archive/, their relative locations and rotations in 3d space and repetitions through assemblies.

Type `xsd.exe /c 3DXMLMesh.xsd` to generate C# class for reading 3d representation of each part (TessPart_*.3DRep).

Unzip the 3DXML file, implement reading of contained `NameSetTree.3dxml` and  all parts `*.3DRep`.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a license of SolidWorks, you can use the api to programmatically open the model and interrogate the features and geometry.  Here's a simple example getting dimensions of sketches and features.

```
SldWorks swApp = new SldWorks();
int nOpenErrors = 0, nOpenWarnings = 0;
string sConfig = string.Empty;
IModelDoc2 doc = swApp.OpenDoc6(sModelName,  (int)swDocumentTypes_e.swDocPART, (int)swOpenDocOptions_e.swOpenDocOptions_Silent, sConfig, ref nOpenErrors, ref nOpenWarnings);

 // extract the features and dimensions
 Feature feat = doc.FirstFeature();
 while(feat != null)
 {
     string sFeatName = feat.Name;
     IDisplayDimension dispDim = feat.GetFirstDisplayDimension();
     if (dispDim != null)
     {
          Dimension dim = dispDim.GetDimension();
          if(dim != null)
          {
            // dim.FullName;
            // dim.GetSystemValue2(sConfig);
          }
          feat = feat.GetNextFeature();
      }
  }

  swApp.ExitApp();
```

Comment: Works great ! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are commercial libraries that can read native Solidworks files and give you the information you want, but I guess this is not what had in mind.

Some of the export formats like STL are very simple formats where you can easily find reader libraries for. STL is a triangle mesh format, so it is also easy to get size and location of the geometry. However, these simple formats do not have any meta information like part/assembly relations. What you can identify by looking at the geometry are not-connected bodies. This may be the same as what you specified as being a "part" in Solidworks, but not always. A part could end up being several bodies and several parts can end up being one body if they touch and the Solidworks STL exporter chooses to merge them (maybe it never does, you'll have to try).

I guess most formats on the list will have this problem of not having any part information. There may be a few more complex formats that have the information (like the native file format itself), but then you will have a hard time finding a (non-commercial) library able to read it.

May it is an option to write a Solidworks plugin/script, that can export every part as a separate STL (or other simple format)?

Comment: Thanks for the Solidworks plugin/script tip! I'll accept this answer unless somebody comes with something more straightforward we're both missing...